# Django get() model query not returning object

Tags: django, get, view, models

What I have is a basic forum. Now, what I'm trying to do is retrieve the post from a topic within the board. Everytime I hit `localhost:8000/boards/1/topics/1` I get the following:

> No Topic matches the given query`

I'm suspicious of the get parameters may be the culprit but I'm unsure of what parameters I must specify in order to retrieve the desired object. Below is the full flow of code, please advise.

**urls.py:**

```
path('boards/<board_id>/topics/<topic_id>', views.topic_posts, name = 'topic_posts')
```

**views.py:**

```
def topic_posts(request, board_id, topic_id):
    topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, board_id = board_id, topic_id = topic_id)
    return render(request, 'topic_posts.html', {'topic': topic})
```

**models:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import datetime

# Create your models here.

class Board(models.Model):
    '''
    id auto generated
    '''
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, unique = True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Topic(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length = 255, default = '')
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now(), blank = True)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, related_name = 'topics', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    starter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'topics', on_delete = models.CASCADE)


class Post(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(max_length = 4000, default = '')
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name = 'posts', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now(), blank = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null = True, default = datetime.now(), blank = True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'posts', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null = True, related_name = '+', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

Best wishes, and thank you for reading!

Comment: You don't have `topic_id` in your `Topic` model. If you want to filter by `Topic` id, then it's either `id` or `pk`.

Comment: @Borut I've tried both id and pk. I still receive the same errors. I tried the following:
get_object_or_404(Topic, board_id = board_id, id = topic_id)

Comment: But the code with topic_id would give a different error. Since you're not seeing that, I guess this isn't the actual view that is being called.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, that's right. It would have returned FieldError exception.Yeah, it can't be this view being called here.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm not sure what you mean. but it is the topic_posts view. I'm getting this error: 
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/boards/1/topics/1
Raised by: boards.views.topic_posts
No Topic matches the given query.

Comment: Are you sure that those results are in DB ? You can check that using `django shell` also

Comment: @RedTears Someone attempted to improve your post by adding the missing spaces in the views.py file content.  Please add them yourself if they are there in your code: otherwise, add them in your code, because Python requires spaces/tabs.

Comment: get_object_or_404(Topic, board__id = board_id, id = topic_id)

Comment: @Vaibhav Using single underscore works too: `get_object_or_404(Topic, board_id=board_id, id=topic_id)`.

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Yeah the results are there they're reflecting on the webpage and the admin console.

Vaibhav I've used that line, still receive the same error D:

Answer (score 1):

### urls.py

```
url(r'^boards/(?P<pk>\d+)/topics/(?P<topic_pk>\d+)/$', views.topic_posts, name='topic_posts'),
```

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/boards/1/topics/84/`

in DB `id` starts from 84(in my db) not from 1. 
so check in your database id where from starts.